# How to delete audio files' meta data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, windows, mp3

I have some MP3s on my Mac. I want to import them into my iPhone. The problem is that, using iTunes, the iPhone automatically create several folders or albums, depending on the **artist**, the **album**, the **genre** (and so on) of one particular MP3 file.

Using Windows it's easy to prevent this, since I can delete manually all of these tags and file information, but using the Mac I seem to not be able to do this. Is there any way to delete this information?

Comment: You don't have to copy the files into the Library and so it creates no new folders - is this what you want?

Comment: It will only create artist / album folders, and maybe a compilation folder. I haven't seen genre folders "and so on"...

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering this because it's the first result in Google and this is a more complete answer to the question title than exists in other Q&As I see.

To reliably remove "Comment" data, macOS file metadata "Where from" URLs, and all regular audio metadata for an audio file like mp3/m4a/m4b including embedded artwork:

### **First check existing metadata:**

- In macOS Finder you may see artwork in the thumbnail of the file, or via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (**File** > **Get Info**).
- To potentially see more complete data that the GUI doesn't show:

  - First install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then do `brew install exiftool`
  - Now in Terminal do both `mdls file.mp3` and `exiftool file.mp3`

### **Remove everything:**

Here is a Terminal method.

**For all file types:**

- To remove macOS "Where from" metadata, do `xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms file.ogg`

**MP3 files:**

- First install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then do  `brew install id3lib`.
- To obliterate all mp3 tags and embedded artwork, do `id3convert -s file.mp3`

**M4A / M4B files:**

- First install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then do `brew install exiftool`
- Do `exiftool -all:all= file.m4b`

**Check metadata again to make sure you have a clean file!**

Answer (score 2):

Within iTunes, you can select the file and press command-I to get the file information. You can then delete all the meta-data associated with the mp3.

Comment: It doesn't work on the Music.app on Catalina. Apparently the app does not save the changes made to the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I simply put the mp3 file in GarageBand and export it as a new mp3 file. Done!